# how to disable retina image scaling in cocos2d-x framework

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, retina-display, cocos2d-x

I'm porting my android game to osx I'm having problems on devices with retina display, the sprites are either unnececary scaled or the sprites offset are scaled and not in place, I'd like to have a possibility to control this by myself.

Is it possible to work in retina mode without scale factor, can I somehow enable usage of a full screen 960x640 and with scale factor still set to 1.0?

Could you please tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable retinal display in `AppDelegate.cpp` file. In your `didFinishLaunching` set RetinaDisplay to false. :) Hope this works