# disable retina display in cocos2d-x 2.2.2

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am trying to disable retina display in cocos2d-x 2.2.2, here is what I've found:

[how to disable retina image scaling in cocos2d-x framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9873341/765498)

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/14240

but looks like, this function has been removed.

just wondering, how to achieve this.